# select2 - "trigger" does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

When I open the drop-down the value I set via jQuery is **highlighted** but doesn't get *triggered/selected*. Clicking on the highlighted option also doesn't do anything until I click the other option and then click the correct one, which is when the trigger fires.

```
<select name="paySelect" id="paySelect" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="paySelect" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="" data-select2-id="2">Select Payment Mode</option>
    <option value="1" data-select2-id="19">Cash on Delivery</option>
    <option value="2" data-select2-id="18">Prepaid</option>
</select>
```

Setting the value:
`$("#paySelect").val("2").trigger('change');`

I have also tried the following:

`$("#paySelect").val("1").trigger('change.select2');`

`$("#paySelect").val("1").change();`

One frustrating or rather interesting thing is that **all work fine in the chrome console**. I am working on someone else's code.

`ver: Select2 4.0.6-rc.1`

```js
 $("#paySelect").select2({ width: '100%'});
 $("#paySelect").val("2").trigger('change');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<select name="paySelect" id="paySelect" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="paySelect" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="" data-select2-id="2">Select Payment Mode</option>
    <option value="1" data-select2-id="19">Cash on Delivery</option>
    <option value="2" data-select2-id="18">Prepaid</option>
</select>
```

**As requested here is the code**

```html
<div class="col-md-4 payment_mode_list">
  <select name="paySelect" id="paySelect" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="paySelect" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="" data-select2-id="8">Select Payment Mode</option>
    <option value="1" data-select2-id="83">COD(Cash on Delivery)</option>
    <option value="2" data-select2-id="84">Prepaid</option>
  </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--open select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="7" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-payment_mode_id-container" aria-owns="select2-payment_mode_id-results"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-payment_mode_id-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Select Payment Mode">Select Payment Mode</span>
  <span
    class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
    </span>
    </span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
    <div class="payment_mode_id_error error_msg"></div>
</div>
```

The following code is probably auto-generated and works only when the select2 dropdown is open

```html
<span class="select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--open" style="position: absolute; top: 1087.38px; left: 130px;"><span class="select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 321px;"><span class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="textbox"></span>
<span
  class="select2-results">
  <ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-payment_mode_id-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
    <li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true" data-select2-id="85">Select Payment Mode</li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-payment_mode_id-result-tva6-1" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-payment_mode_id-result-tva6-1">COD(Cash on Delivery)</li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-payment_mode_id-result-kust-2" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-payment_mode_id-result-kust-2">Prepaid</li>
  </ul>
  </span>
  </span>
  </span>
```

Please ignore any mismatch/misspellings in ID or class name from the examples shared while asking question and now.

Comment: More input here is needed perhaps.  Try to include the code that can reproduce this IN the question so we may best assist you here.

Comment: I made a snippet of your code (which works) please update THAT to reproduce your issue here.

Comment: Code snippet works!

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have included the code. Hope this narrows it down.

Comment: @Alaindeseine yes even my jquery val change and trigger works in chrome's console but not from the code written in the website itself.

Comment: There is probably some syncing problem in your DOM. Perhaps the select2 is initializing after the trigger call. You could try to debug it with setTimeout to be sure if is this

Answer (score -1):

The right code is, for example:

```
$('#paySelect').val('').trigger('change');
```

You can also notify only select2 with indicating a namespace:

```
$('#paySelect').val('').trigger('change.select2');
```

Select2 trigger documentation: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#triggering-events

Comment: Are you referring to the single and double quotes or should I set the value to `''` first? Both ways are not working by the way.

Comment: No matter with simple or double quote. Just the right way to trigger the change event.

Comment: This answer seems to be effectively the same as the code in the question.

Comment: The question tell about 3 different syntax, i just confirm the good one.

Comment: @Alaindeseine but none of these are working as I mentioned in the question. Is there something else I am missing? Why is your `val('')` empty?

Comment: Can you add in your question every things about the problem, like for example the select2 function call.